# HTTP gzip JSON not decoded in Firefox

Tags: json, apache, http, compression, lighttpd

I am sending a GET request for JSON data to my proxy server via lighttpd:

```
Firefox -> lighttpd -> proxy server
```

Lighttpd is configured for gzipped json via the following line in lighttpd.conf:

```
compress.filetype = ( "application/json", "application/javascript", …)
```

The proxy server gzips the JSON, adds

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Encoding: "gzip"
```

to the HTTP response header, and sends the response to lighttpd, which forwards it to the client.

When Firefox receives the response, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

So there is something wrong with the compressed JSON (or its interpretation). I checked that the compressed JSON data has the same hash as if I save the uncompressed JSON to file and gzip it on the command line.

Can anyone offer any insight as to why Firefox won't interpret the compressed JSON?

Comment: `Content-Endcoding` - is that just a typo in your question, or copied from your code?

Comment: Typo - fixed now.

Comment: Is the value of the Content-Encoding header field really quoted?

Comment: yes it is. I also tried  unquoting it and got a
 Content Encoding Error: The page you are trying to view cannot be shared because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

Comment: Have you tried making the request with a different client, e.g. curl?  Include Accept-Encoding: gzip in the request headers.

Comment: After some thrashing, I discovered that I had my Content-Encoding setting wrong - I had been using deflate instead of gzip for my json compression. So I just changed to 

    Content-Encoding: deflate

Comment: This is a known bug (or not implemented feature) https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1556507